# Can you use your own database for Facebook applications?

Tags: mysql, database, facebook

I am completely new to Facebook application development, but I've got a straight-forward question.

I am looking to create an application that would collect a few pieces of information from a user and store it into a database. I wanted to host the database on a MySQL server, but I didn't know how Facebook works with application information and data storage.

My question is - does Facebook allow off-site databases to host information in applications?

Comment: I am looking to find out how to store and retrieve data within a Facebook app.

Comment: "I am looking to find out how to store and retrieve data within a Facebook app" --- do it like you would for any non-facebook app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep. Mine does. It doesn't matter where the application gets the data from. the most important thing is that it is an iframe, so you are free to do whatever you want on your server.

Comment: So, you have an app within an iFrame that has PHP and connects out to a database?