# Use data of own database in facebook application

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I want to develop a Facebook application which shows the data from database from my own server.

I have found one question here : [Can you use your own database for Facebook applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764819/can-you-use-your-own-database-for-facebook-applications)

But like above question I don't want to use iFrame to show my content on Facebook application.

Any solution for this as, I am new to Facebook application development.

**Edit:**

**Simplified version**: I have a page in my server which generate xml feed of the product. So can I read this xml feed url in facebook Application?

Comment: no iFrame = no app with access to own database!

Comment: iFrames are the only way! There is no canvas option now I believe, but that would have limited you from using a database. So... Man up and use an iFrame.

Comment: I don't see why you are having problems with this, because php retrieves data from mysql, and php sends the info to the facebook app. It is as easy as to display a variable in your facebook app. I know facebook apps development doesn't always work as it is supposed to, but in this case facebook cannot screw this up for you. P.S. i have done this with canvas before.

Comment: I have edited my question with more details.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all applications use an iframe to display the actual app, I don't think you'll be able to avoid it.  What you put into that iframe however is entirely yours.  It runs from your server, and so can use whatever back end you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Why don'T you want to use iFrame? FBML & Iframes are only ways you can show your content with !